# Changing color of the messages in Texmaker?

Tags: texmaker

I can't read the Texmaker messages when I'm using dark mode on my desktop environment ( Kubuntu 20.04 with global theme breeze dark ), which makes the background of Texmaker messages/log dark. The messages are dark blue so I can barely see them against a dark background. I could not find the option to change it in the configure texmaker -> editor -> colors. Am I looking in the wrong place? The only way to see the messages for me was to set my desktop global theme to light, but I really don't like to have to do this just for one program.

Version:
Texmaker 5.0.3
(compiled with Qt 5.12.8)

Comment: Have you considered switching to texstudio? It once started out as a texmaker fork, but gained a lot of nice features along the way. It also has nice support for dark mode: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7szN.png

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Wonderful, that looks better in dark mode.